# Is there a way to see if all online members in a discord server are playing a game -- discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a command for my discord bot using discord.py which return a list of everyone playing a certain game.

This is the code I have so far:

```
@client.command()
async def members_info(ctx):
    server_members = ctx.guild.members
    data = [member.name for member in server_members if "ActivityType.playing" in member.activity]
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f'Server Members', description=f'{data}', color=discord.Color.dark_gray())
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

The code returns an error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: argument of type 'Game' is not iterable
```

I am novice at Python and a beginner at using the discord.py library. This is also my first stack overflow post, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just going to point out that you don't need an f-string in `description = f'data'`
You could just do `embed = discord.Embed(title=f'Server Members', description= data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`member.activity`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.ActivityType) has an [`ActivityType`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.ActivityType) that lets you figure out what the activity is. However, sometimes this attribute doesn't exist, so you can just return `False`.

```py
def is_game(activity):
    try:
        return activity.type == discord.ActivityType.playing
    except AttributeError:  # sometimes it could be a `BaseActivity` or `Spotify`
        return False

@client.command()
async def members_info(ctx):
    server_members = ctx.guild.members
    data = [member.name for member in server_members if is_game(member.activity)]
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f'Server Members', description='\n'.join(data), color=discord.Color.dark_gray())
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Hi Eric. Thanks for your post. This makes sense in my head and resolved the attribute error. However, the bot will only send a list with its own name in it. Not sure as to why this is happening. I though the list comprehension would loop through all of the members in the server.

Comment: Do you have presence intents enabled? Discord marks them as privileged, so you'll need to enable them in your application and [in your code](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=presence#discord.Intents.presences).

Comment: I did have intents enabled both in code and on the Dev portal. For some reason I think I changed "intents = discord.Intents().all()" to "intents = discord.Intents().default()". This fixed the issue. Thank you.